# Using angular to conditionally hide text content inside of bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using a bootsrap tooltip with a lot of dynamic content. I know you can use html inside the tooltip `data-title`but it seems like you can't use angular directives like `ng-if`

Is there a way to do something like:

```
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle editable-question" bs-tooltip data-

    html="true" data-title="<span ng-if='function == true'> {{obj.field}}
</span> other content that will always be here" >
```

I haven't been able to use `ng-if` inside of the `data-title` string.

What is the best way to conditionally hide/show some of the text content inside of a tooltip?

Comment: `data-title="{{function ? 'text' : '' }}"`. Is it working for you?

Comment: @Nick wait so if I did-
`data-title="{{function ? 'text' : 'dog' }}"`
should I expect this to work such that when the function is true it will display 'dog'?

Comment: `if (function == true) { 'text' } else { 'dog' }`

Comment: @Nick that almost works, but the problem is that the text I need to display comes from a scope variable. It will work when I'm just using regular text but this won't work: `data-title="{{function ? '{{obj.attr}}' : '' }}"`

Comment: `data-title="{{function ? obj.attr : '' }}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data-title="{{function ? obj.attr : '' }}"
```